# Adding an element that is declared on the stack to a static array

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, static, move

Let's say I have a std::vector which is declared as static. Can I add objects, which are declared locally on the stack of a calling function to the vector without repercussions?

From my understanding, the vector stores its elements on the heap. Meaning if I tell the vector to MOVE the element like this

```
myvector.push_back(std::move(element));
```

it will be stored on the heap and its visibility will be preserved, right?

Edit: I would want to avoid the object from being copied because it manages other resources.

Am I correct? Or can this be done easier?

Comment: Usually objects are *copied* into the vector, so no need to do anything special really.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your answer! I should have mentioned, that I want to avoid copying the object because it manages resources and copying the object would mess up the program.

Comment: Then moving (like you do) should work just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

You generally can copy initialise objects with dynamic storage by copying from objects with automatic or static storage and vice versa. Whether the object is copied by moving does not matter.

There can in theory be classes that only work correctly when allocated in certain way, but such classes should be made non-copiable to prevent problems.

Comment: "There can in theory be classes that only work correctly when allocated in certain way" - I have often heard talk of such mystery/magical classes that know whether they are allocated on the free store or have automatic storage duration. In my 20+ years of writing C++ I have not yet seen one (except for some *very* contrived and highly platform specific examples, created just to prove a point). Nor have I encountered a situation where I would want/need an object to know that. Care to give a (useful) example?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Actual case that I've encountered is a logging related singleton class from Ogre3D library. If you wanted to pass arguments to its constructor, you had to create dynamic instance with `new`, because the constructor would register the first created instance as the singleton and the library would delete it upon shutdown. I'm sure there were some advantages, but I doubt that would have been the only way to solve whatever problem that design solved.